# Loopback Model Relations not saving properly?

Tags: mysql, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop, database-relations

PATIENT MODEL

```
{
  "name": "Patient",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "createdDate": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "profile": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Profile",
      "foreignKey": "profileID"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

PATIENT TABLE

```
id (INT)
createdDate (DATETIME)
modifiedDate (DATETIME)
```

PROFILE MODEL

```
{
  "name": "Profile",
  "base": "Model",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "patient": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Patient",
      "foreignKey": "profileID"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

PROFILE TABLE

```
id (INT)
firstName (VARCHAR)
lastName (VARCHAR)
```

Q: When I save the model, I POST following to /api/patients/ endpoint

```
{
  "ceratedDate": "2012-12-12",
  "modifiedDate": "2012-12-13",
  "profile": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Wick"
  }
}
```

The way I expect it to work is save createdDate and modifiedDate to Patient Table and save firstName and lastName to Profile Table.

Why is this not working ? 
Do I have to do any additional work to get it to work ?
When GETting it it only returns Patient model without profile object in it. Is that the same issue I guess ?

Any help is appreciated, thanks !

Comment: You do have a typo in your POST, `ceratedDate` isn't `createdDate` like I assume you expect it.  Does that fix it?

Comment: Just a typo @BryanClark

Comment: I created an [issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1586)

Answer (score 0):

LoopBack doesn't support the batch update for the related models. You'll have to update Patient/Profile model separately. Feel free to open an issue at https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/issues.

Comment: and how would that work if the relation is `"type": "embedsMany",` and the data source of the related resource is `"dataSource": "transient",`?
I cannot seem to find out, how to create such objects with the `EntityClass.create()` method.